# Upload Files using Explorer with Metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, open-with-explorer, explorer

Most of our users tend to just upload files to Document Library using the explorer. 
This leads to a lot of files not having the necessary Metadata and the Document Library not being very sufficient.

We use SharePoint Online

Is there a way for the user to get prompt to add Metadata when using the Explorer to upload files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not support to edit document properties when upload file via file explorer.

As a workaround, I recommend you using “Quick Edit” to bulk edit document metadata in SharePoint Online classic view.

Comment: Is there a way to  can notify users that these files have not been filled with metadata. like a notification or alert. I can't use Flow

Comment: You can set the columns as required in SharePoint UI, then if the columns are not be filled, it will display alert icon. You can also create a workflow in SharePoint Designer, start the workflow when the item is created, check if the current item column is empty, if so, send an email to created by column user.

Comment: Can you please tell me how would I go on creating a workflow that will check which dates are not filled with metadata and alert the user once a week to fill them in ?